# Using Server Request and Response filters for ThreadLocal storage in a RestEasy based service

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, resteasy, thread-local

I am currently working on a RESTeasy based RESTful service. I have a filter class which serves as a server request filter as well as a server response filter (i.e. it implements `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` interfaces).

At the beginning of the request, I use the filter to put an object into `ThreadLocal`. This object is used by the resources throughout the request. At the end of the request, before sending out the response, the filter removes the object from `ThreadLocal`.

My question is that is there a guarantee that the the request filter, the resource and the response filter will all execute in the same thread? Is there a possibility that after the request filter puts the object into `ThreadLocal`, a different thread will execute the request (and thus not have access to the object)?

I was sure that this was the case but then I saw this http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Does-filter-method-of-ContainerRequestFilter-run-in-resource-method-thread-td7582648.html (official Jersey forum) and now I have doubts.

Comment: on the comment/link of the jersey forum regarding asynchronous handling: asynchronous handling means a client gets a response immediately, doesn's it? - But that does not imply that the servlet container thread which handles the client's request in the first place will change after having send the client's response. If it is true, that is an indicator for me that ThreadLocal could be used for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

> javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext.setProperty(...)

and

> javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext.getProperty(...)

are probably the right approach. The javadoc states:

> In a Servlet container, the properties are synchronized with the ServletRequest and expose all the attributes available in the ServletRequest. Any modifications of the properties are also reflected in the set of properties of the associated ServletRequest.

Comment: It can be that easy. Thank you very much for that one, saved us a lot of trouble.